# Is it possible to get a list of all open PRs in a git repo without using the HTTPS API or the `gh` CLI tool?

Tags: bash, git

Is it possible to get a list of all open PRs in a git repo without using the HTTPS API or the `gh` CLI tool?

`git shortlog -n` seems to show a list of all ever opened PRs. I would like to get a list of only  PRs that are open.

I would like a solution that doesn't use the `gh` CLI tool or HTTPs API pinging because those require additional authentication, which I'm trying to avoid in my bash script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Pull requests are not a Git feature.  They are implemented by GitHub, using the database in GitHub that can only be queried through the GitHub API.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want pull requests for github, not just any git repository (because that is not possible).

I think this does what you want:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/pulls?state=open
```

And it does not need authentication (assuming public git repositories).

Answer (score 1):

Possible via ssh not via https
You can use the below command to fetch the active PRs
git fetch --tags --progress --depth=200 -- ssh://git<source_repo>.git/sources/<source_repo>.git +refs/pull-requests/*/from:refs/remotes/<source_repo>/pr/* +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/<source_repo>/master